# MY SQL QUERY DATA ARRANGING

Tags: mysql

Let's say i have a mysql query that results in the following lines .

```
col1data  col2data1  col3data col4data 
col1data  col2data2  col3data col4data  
col1data  col2data3  col3data col4data
```

note that the data in the all columns bar second one is the same .
My question : is there any way via query to have the results in this form

```
col1data col3data col4data col2data1 col2data2 col2data3
```

putting the different data on the same line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the records from `col2` combined into a single delimited string, you can *group* the table using MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT   col1, col3, col4, GROUP_CONCAT(col2)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY col1, col3, col4
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7f08/1/0).

Comment: OK now what if my data is like that
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  col1 VARCHAR(255),
  col2 VARCHAR(255),
  col3 VARCHAR(255),
  col4 VARCHAR(255)
);
 
INSERT INTO my_table
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('a', 'col2data1', 'aa', 'aaa'),
  ('a', 'col2data2', 'aa', 'aaa'),
  ('a', 'col2data3', 'aa', 'aaa'),
  ('b', 'col2data11', 'bb', 'bbb'),
  ('b', 'col2data22', 'bb', 'bbb'),
  ('b', 'col2data33', 'bb', 'bbb')
;
imagine many more rows .

Comment: @user2515601: Then the above query will return a result for every distinct combination of `(col1, col3, col4)`.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is:  do you know how many values you have for col2data?

The canonical answer is to use `group_concat()` to get the values:

```
select col1data, col3data, col4data, group_concat(col2data)
from t
group by col1data, col3data, col4data;
```

This creates a comma separated list.  You could get fancy and include spaces instead of commas:

```
select col1data, col3data, col4data, group_concat(col2data separator ' ')
from t
group by col1data, col3data, col4data;
```

But, that still produces just four columns.

If you want a separate column for each one *and* you know the number, you can use a trick on `group_concat()`:

```
select col1data, col3data, col4data,
       substring_index(group_concat(col2data order by col2data), ',', 1), 
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(col2data order by col2data), ',', 2), ',', -1),
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(col2data order by col2data), ',', 3), ',', -1),
from t
group by col1data, col3data, col4data;
```

The use of `substring_index()` allows you to extract the elements from the list after they are concatenated together.

Comment: but that will greatly impact the execution time would it not ? :(

Comment: @user2515601 . . . Which?  All of these should be pretty similar in execution time.  The time for a group by is really in the aggregation step more than the "calculate the functions" step.